# How to get UITableView's FooterView to be visible?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I set the tableview's footerView like this :

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, 45.0f);
```

then my cellCount*cellHeight > tableview.frame.size.height.
then I find that footerView can't be show. Must to pull the tableview that it show. How to solve it?

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.tableView.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, 45.0f);

//It can't to solve My Problem
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Comment: do you want your footer view to be visible at *all* times or just when the user scrolls to the bottom of the table?

Comment: Thanks! 
I want footer view to be visible just when the user scrolls to the bottom of the table. all times: Use heightForFooterInSection delegate ? or other way?

Answer (score 0):

Create `footerView` (by code or in `xib`). Then use following *delegate* methods:

```
    - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
           return footerView.frame.size.height;
    }
    - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
           return footerView;
    }
```

In your case you might not be returning the height for footer.

Comment: Thanks! I set the navigationItem's rightBarbuttonItem to edit/done my tableview(Create by xib).I want to show the footerView when tableview is editing and then hide the footerView when the tableView is not editing. I know reloadData could work. But is it that has other way to solve it ? Because I really don't want to change the data when I just edit it. Thanks!